# BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead` in React/Express App

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, dependencies, package.json

When I run 'npm start', the app starts just fine but 'npm run build' gives me the following message in the terminal:

```
> workout_tracker@0.1.0 build /Users/*******/mern-workout/client
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/Components/UI/Spinner/Spinner.module.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! workout_tracker@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the workout_tracker@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/*******/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T23_21_04_691Z-debug.log
```

I've searched but, the only solutions seem to be for people using Angular who are having some issue with their Bootstrap version. I am not using Bootstrap in my app.

I tried removing "not dead" from the browserslist array just to see what would happen and i got this:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file: 

    ./node_modules/query-string/index.js:8 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! workout_tracker@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the workout_tracker@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/******/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T23_41_55_488Z-debug.log
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "workout_tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.3.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.7",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "jw-paginate": "^1.0.2",
    "jw-react-pagination": "^1.0.7",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.2.0",
    "random-id": "0.0.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-headroom": "^2.2.2",
    "react-icons-kit": "^1.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts-cssmodules": "^1.1.10",
    "react-swipe-to-delete-component": "^0.3.4",
    "react-swipeout": "^1.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

Comment: I just got this when I tried to do a production build of my app. Looks like it is an issue with the webpack cssloader. I removed the `browserlist` from my file and it built without errors.

Comment: My browserlist is still there.  I'm having trouble recalling exactly what the issue was.  I believe I removed a dependency that was ultimately unnecessary which required an older version of another dependency.

Comment: @hsimah, thanks for the solution, but could you please how it works when we delete object `browserlist` from a package.json file?

Answer (score 47):

When using React please take a look into your `package.json`. You may find the following added there.

```
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

Remove **"not dead",** and run `yarn run build` again. Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I'm in an old version, but the `not dead` line I had to remove to fix this was in a file called "browserslist".

Comment: You are correct..!

Answer (score 6):

'dead' description comes in the newer versions. In other words 'dead' is not defined in ../node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus/node_modules/browserslist/index.js.

If you open the above ../browserlist/index.js file, you will see:

```
var QUERIES = [
  {
    regexp: /^last\s+(\d+)\s+major versions?$/i,
    select: function (context, versions) ...
  },
  ...,
]
```

You can add the following in there:

```
{
  regexp: /^dead$/i,
  select: function (context) {
    var dead = ['ie <= 10', 'ie_mob <= 10', 'bb <= 10', 'op_mob <= 12.1']
    return resolve(dead, context)
  }
}
```

That worked fine for me without changing the dependency version in the package-json.lock

Comment: Charming solution @rdzcn. I think you are working with node people.

Answer (score 2):

It happens if you have another tool, which uses very old Browserslist.

Call `npm ls`, find who use Browserslist < 4 and open issue there to update dependencies.

Comment: The problem is maybe one of its dependencies used that.

Answer (score 1):

Set `"browserslist": []` in `package.json`

Comment: this defeats the purpose of browserlist

Answer (score 1):

```
browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],



 ***ok****
    browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
```

Comment: Delete  "not dead" ,  then npm run build, enjoy!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Updating `autoprefixer` fixed it:

```sh
npm i autoprefixer
```

Answer (score 0):

Update css-loader to 1.0.0. It will fix this problem if the browsers-list doesnot solve the problem

```
 npm i css-loader@1.0.0
```

Reference : https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/266

Answer (score 0):

just ran into this problem and solved it.

There are two browserlist entries in your package.json file, and the default one is the "production". This is what the text looks like by default:

```
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  }
```

This is with the added **development** parameter:

```
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [

    ]
  }
```

That should resolve the bottleneck.

I believe React runs production by default, and building an application with older dependencies is prevented by the default build command (for safety reasons).

Answer (score -2):

If you dont have the codes in package.json as answered by 'Matthis Kohli' just add those lines except the "not dead" part, it should look like this

```
"browserslist": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not ie <= 11",
  "not op_mini all"
]
```

Comment: you just copied his post?