# Failed to compile: Unknown browser query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I was working on my react app. But now when I type "npm run build", It shows this error

```
Failed to compile.

Unknown browser query `op_   all`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
```

I tried uninstalling node modules and running that command again but nothing works and the error remains. Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939103/browserslisterror-unknown-browser-query-dead-in-react-express-app/53308299